# how to pass value from output to a string in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.4

I've been trying to make an application in python and I'm new to python.
Well, what I actually want to do is that . I want the feedparser to read the values from an RSS of a website... say reddit... and then I want to make that output as a stringand pass the value further to my code... my code right now..

```
import feedparser
import webbrowser

feed = feedparser.parse('http://www.reddit.com/.rss')
print feed['entries'][1]['title'] 
print feed['entries'][1]['link']
```

It is working right now.. it parses the feed and I get the output I want... Now, I want to use the "link" from the "print feed['entries'][1]['link'] " and use it in the code further...
how can I do so..? To be more specific.. I want to open that URL in my browser...
I concluded to something like this..

```
import feedparser
import webbrowser

feed = feedparser.parse('http://www.reddit.com/.rss')
print feed['entries'][1]['title'] 
print feed['entries'][1]['link'] 

mystring = 'feed['entries'][1]['link']'
webbrowser.open('mystring')
```

It is of course not working... Please Help... if you need to know anything else.. please let me know...

Comment: if any answer solves your question please mark it as the answer.

Comment: `feed['entries'][1]['link']` is already a string. You don't need to put it in quotes. (And, uh, the quotes are causing syntax errors, which you can see in your question because the syntax highlighting is all confused. To cast to a string, use `str()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the `feed[entries][1][link]` as a string, just pass the value inside to the webbrowser.

Example -

```
webbrowser.open(feed['entries'][1]['link'])
```

Comment: worked to some extent.. it opened in IE (not my default browser) and it went in google search... and not as the URL itself... But, thank you.. you gave me an idea... I did this and it worked like I wanted.... I used this..  url = feed['entries'][1]['link']
webbrowser.open(url)

Comment: Your solution is exactly same same using the one I gave, you are just doing an extra step of saving the url in a variable. Anyway glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

This is Reddit specific so it won't work on other RSS feeds but I thought this might help you.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import praw


r = praw.Reddit("my_cool_user_agent")
submissions = r.get_front_page()
for x in submissions:
    print("Title: {0} URL: {1} Permalink: {2}".format(x, x.url, x.permalink))
    print ("------------------------------------------------------------")
```

For Reddit there are 2 URLs that you might be interested in: the actual link that is submitted (the 'external' link... think imgur, etc) and the permalink to the Reddit post itself.

Comment: Anand's reply gave me an Idea.. and I solved it what I wanted..  So, Here is what I did.. I made a string called URL and called it my browser.. So, now, it opens the feed in my default browser..
` url = feed['entries'][1]['link']
webbrowser.open(url) `

Thank You guys.. :)